# RDP - Cannot connect two particular machines over Internet

Tags: remote-desktop

I have 3 PC's - Desktop, Laptop (both W10) and Dedicated Server (W2016)

Desktop and Laptop can connect to each other when on LAN but not over Internet.

Laptop can connect to Dedicated Server over Internet and Dedicated Server can connect to Desktop over Internet so all settings look okay.

I can create a pass through connection via the Dedicated Server to connect to the Desktop from the Laptop. I can not, however, get the Laptop to connect directly to the Desktop over the Internet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify where these 3 machines are in relation to each other. Are they all on the same LAN, or on different LANs, etc?

Comment: At home, the desktop and the laptop are on the same LAN and can access each other when on the LAN. It's when I'm away from home and trying to RDP into the desktop that the problem arises. . The Dedicated Server is with a host in Germany and only accessible by RDP.

Answer (score 0):

All of a sudden, the problem has disappeared, I can now connect from he laptop to the desktop over the Internet. I haven't changed anything whatsoever, it just started working. One of the vagaries of Windows, I guess.